# SQL Query 4 way join to find who's NOT there

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables... users, friends, articles & article_shares (as in written)

A user can share an article they have created by simply inviting them to read it. What I'm trying find is a list of friends of the article creator (id 63) who have not been invited to share the article yet (id 34).

So, table users:

```
user_id - name 
10         Dan
11         Doug
12         Chad
13         Ben
63         John
```

table friends

```
user_id - friends_id
63        10
63        11
63        12
63        13
```

table articles

```
article_id - user_id_creator
34           63
```

table article_shares

```
article_id - user_id_sharedWith
34           10
34           11
```

From the data above I want to return users with id 12 & 13.. chad & ben

Here's what I'm trying:

```
select u.name, u.user_id, u.live_prof_pic from users u
join friends f on f.user_id = u.user_id 
join articles a on a.user_id_creator = f.friends_id
join article_shares as on as.articl_id <> a.article_id
where ((f.friends = '63') && (a.article_id = '34'))
```

It is simply returning 0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try,

```
SELECT  c.friends_ID
FROM    articles a
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON a.user_Id_creator = b.user_ID
        INNER JOIN friends c
            ON b.user_ID = c.user_ID
        LEFT JOIN article_shares d
            a.article_ID = d.article_ID
WHERE   b.user_ID = 63 AND
        a.article_ID = 34 AND
        d.article_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: can you provide dummy records?

Comment: thanks too, what records do you want to get? and also the columns.

Comment: I want to return the user data for the friends who are not sharing article_id 34 which is users 12 & 13 so return for them u.name, u.user_id, u.live_prof_pic

Comment: @DarrenSweeney How about this one? [Click this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a6dd/14)

Comment: Brilliant! I thought I had this join thing sorted but that's a whole next level it seems! Really appreciate your time and help, many thanks John.